# My Stored Procedure Always return 0

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

the table tblidset does not contain anything at first run, then when I invoked this stored procedure for the first time in my code it should just get the highest value from a table so as to build upon that value later as the program data grows. Problem that bugs me is that it always return 0 on first run. Stuck for a few hours now dumbfounded. care to help? Here's my script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATENEWID
@TYPE AS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @CNT AS INT;
DECLARE @DOCNO AS BIGINT;
DECLARE @DOCID AS BIGINT;
SELECT @CNT = ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) FROM TBLIDSET

--CHECK IF THERE IS NO VALUE AS OF DATE AND INSERT DEFAULT VALUES
    IF @CNT = 0

    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TBLIDSET SELECT TOP 1(DOCID),0 FROM INVHDR ORDER BY DOCID DESC
    END
    DECLARE @NUM AS INT;
    IF @TYPE = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TBLIDSET SET DOCID = DOCID +1
            SELECT @NUM = DOCID FROM TBLIDSET
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TBLIDSET SET DOCNO = DOCNO + 1
            SELECT @NUM = DOCNO FROM TBLIDSET
    END
    PRINT @NUM
    RETURN @NUM

END
GO
```

Comment: What do you pass for the Type parameter?

Comment: Using `MAX+1` as an ID is a *problem* because it can easily result in duplicate values. Besides, this code doesn't look for the *maximum* ID, it just returns a random number. `SELECT @NUM = DOCID FROM TBLIDSET` may return *any* of the underlying values

Comment: Instead of trying to generate your own sequences, use SQL Server's [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) feature, available since SQL Server 2012. Which version are you using?

Comment: Consider using `OUTPUT` variable. `RETURN` is meant for indicating success or error code. You are going against convention.

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos, sad to say I am forced to use MSSQL 2000 as it is the one thats being currently utilized in our office. Btw,  TBLIDSET only contains one row, so that everytime an instance or any part of my application invokes the procedure, it automatically increment the value first and return it thereafter so as to prevent duplicates as my app employs a lot of background worker that generates docno and docid when its running. type is only 1 and 2, I pass 1 when i need a new docid and 2 when I need a docno. Thanks by the way to all who tried to help me out! :)

Comment: SQL Server 2000 reached end-of-life about a decade ago. Whatever you do with it you can probably do with SQL Server Express nowadays. Never mind the security vulnerabilities that were discovered and solved since, eg the Slammer worm

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I add output parameter to your code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATENEWID
@TYPE AS INT,
@NUM AS INT OUT  --Declare ouput parameter here
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @CNT AS INT;
DECLARE @DOCNO AS BIGINT;
DECLARE @DOCID AS BIGINT;
SELECT @CNT = ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) FROM TBLIDSET

--CHECK IF THERE IS NO VALUE AS OF DATE AND INSERT DEFAULT VALUES
    IF @CNT = 0

    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TBLIDSET SELECT TOP 1(DOCID),0 FROM INVHDR ORDER BY DOCID DESC
    END
    --Move your @NUM to output parameter
    IF @TYPE = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TBLIDSET SET DOCID = DOCID +1
            SELECT @NUM = DOCID FROM TBLIDSET
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TBLIDSET SET DOCNO = DOCNO + 1
            SELECT @NUM = DOCNO FROM TBLIDSET
    END
    PRINT @NUM
    RETURN @NUM

END
GO
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? `RETURN` isn't broken. If `@NUM` has a value `RETURN` will return it.

Comment: I think his first run result is execution result code. 0 is success. I would like to help him by OUT parameter.